# How can i find the text or id of the below span ..?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

```
var s = "sum",     
ispan = $("<span>").text(s).addClass(s).attr({ title: s });
    ispan.insertBefore("#Button1");
    var sp = $("#" + s);
    alert(sp);
    alert(sp.name);
```

here i created a span and inserted. i would like to find the id of the same span.
i mean the same - `.text(s)`

How can i find the text or id of this span ..?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. The `span` element does not have an ID. You can get the text with `.text()` (obviously?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating it without an id, it won't have an id. You can specify an ID when you create it via attr:

```
ispan = $("<span>").text(s).addClass(s).attr({ title: s, id: MYSPANID });
```

Change 'MYSPANID' to something appropriate.

Once you have an id on the span you can easily select it later (and grab its text) with an id selector:

```
$('#MYSPANID').text();
```

or

```
$('#MYSPANID').html();
```

as appropriate.

Comment: ispan = $("<span>").text(s).addClass(s).attr({ title: s, id: s}); and get it like: $('#'+ s).text();

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given it an `id`, try this:

```
var s = "sum",     
ispan = $("<span>").attr('id',s).text(s).addClass(s).attr({ title: s });
ispan.insertBefore("#Button1");
var sp = $('#' + s)
alert(sp.text()); // alerts "sum"
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/p9tWB/